# ¿Cómo cambiar la función del botón Atrás?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Quiero cambiar la función de un botón de atrás en Xcode, en un UINavigationController, para que ejecute otra acción cuando haga el popviewcontroller

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Por favor, lee [ask] y agrega un [repro] de lo que ya has intentado.

Comment: A qué te refieres con otra acción? Ejecutar una función?

Comment: Especificamente qué buscas hacer ? Que se muestre X vista fuera de tu flujo ?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer varias cosas, según lo que quieras ejecutar.

Puedes añadir la función en el método `viewDidDisappear`, o en el `deinit`

Si por ejemplo, lo que quieres hacer es mostrar un alert o algo así, no te quedará otra opción que hacer tu propio botón simulando el botón de atrás para ejecutar lo que tu quieras.

Comment: Puedes agregar el código de las dos opciones que mencionas?